# Adding a total in a cell when a checkbox is ticked in an adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets

On my budget spreadsheet, in the 'amount' column is the different direct debits going out each month, then I tick the checkbox in the 'gone out?' column when it goes from my account. I'm wanting to add up the the different amounts in the 'amount' in the highlighted cell when a checkbox gets ticked. I'm using Google sheets on android

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your amounts are in the range B3:B23 (for example - I can't see the range from your screenshot), then you could use:

```
=sum(filter(B3:B23,D3:D23))
```

We are generating an array corresponding to all amounts where the corresponding *gone out* tickbox has been ticked, then summing them.

Comment: Thankyou, exactly what I wanted